# Predicted values does not fit test values LSTM Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to fit a LSTM model and when doing prediction, it seems the predicted values do not quite fit the test data. It can be seen here.

[image: Not good as expected]

The here is my code:

Dependencies

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
%matplotlib inline

#ML stuff
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
```

Import data:

```
yf.pdr_override()
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo("0118.KL",start="2018-01-01",end="2020-04-30")

df.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=False)

df.columns = [str(x).lower().replace(' ','_') for x in df.columns]

df = df.drop(['open','high','low','close','volume'],axis=1)

df = df.set_index('date')
df.tail()
```

Data preparation:

```
n_input = 10 #because I want to forecast 10 days into the future, use past 10 days to derive future value
n_features=1
train,test=df[:-n_input],df[-n_input:]

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaler.fit(train)
train = scaler.transform(train) #returns 2d array, of [inputs/time_steps,features] which is 1, because univariate timeseries
test = scaler.transform(test)
```

Train model:

```
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(train,train,length=n_input,batch_size=128) #batch size means the number of samples shown before updating weight of NN
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200,activation='relu',input_shape=(n_input,n_features)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse')
model.fit_generator(generator,epochs=100)
```

Prediction:

```
pred_list = [] #list of arrays, in which each array has one value
batch = train[-n_input:].reshape(1,n_input,n_features)
#it takes the prediction,appends it to the next batch, then use it to predict the next value, like a moving window that updates
# with the predicted value
for i in range(n_input):
    pred_list.append(model.predict(batch)[0]) #one value,returns a list of value, which has only one value actually
    batch = np.append(batch[:,1:,:],[[pred_list[i]]],axis=1)#append to the end of the batch list,axis=1 column

df_predict = pd.DataFrame(scaler.inverse_transform(pred_list),index = df[-n_input:].index,columns=['Predictions'])

df_test = pd.concat([df,df_predict],axis=1)
```

Show graph which can be seen above:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
plt.plot(df_test['adj_close'][-n_input:])
plt.plot(df_test['Predictions'],color="r")
plt.show()
```

Any clue to why it is so? Thank you for reading, any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is predicting small movements, it's just that it is not sensitive enough.

You could look into a few things like,
1. Initialization of Weight Matrix of the Neural Network.
2. Tweaking the `batch_size`
3. Tweaking the number of `epochs`, maybe it needs more epochs and this is 'underfitting' severely.

Also, I would recommend treating the COVID duration data separately.

Comment: What do you mean by initialization matrix?

Comment: Any Neural Network has a weight matrix that automatically adjusts as a result of the backpropagation property of the network. However, the way you initialize the starting values of these weights can give you drastic differences in the way a NN predicts/regresses. https://www.deeplearning.ai/ai-notes/initialization/ is an excellent demonstration of the same. These weight inits MIGHT help the cost minimization algorithm in the weight/cost hyperspace reach a 'better' minima.